# Datagrid binding to collection, problem with one column converting

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding, converters

i have one problem with binding one column of my datagrid in custom way.
So, i have this code in view:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="State">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Background="" Content="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource measureConv}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My Converter:

```
public class MeasureToStateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Measure m;
        try
        {
            m = (Measure)value;
            if (m.Value > 100)
            {
                return "Alarm";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debugger.Log(0, "Convertery", "Bład Convertera MeasureToState" + ex.Message);
        }
        return "Normal";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Content and Background Properties are custom. I use converter to check if my collection object fulfill some condition end return String YES, or  NO, but if  i want to have string field YES in one color background and if it is NO i another color.

How can i do it easy?
I feel that write second converter is little stupid.

Answer (score 1):

You could create two `DataTemplates` with the two respective labels and use a [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) instead of a value converter to get the right template.

Comment: I just implemented a solution using DataTemplateSelector and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Background property of the Label to it's own Content property and use a converter to return the desired Brush:

```
<Label Background="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource ContentToBrushConverter}"/>
```

The converter will receive the value of the Content property... If it equals "Yes" return Brushes.Green, if it equals "No" return Brushes.Red

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the converter to set the background and alter the content using a DataTrigger.
I've assummed the field in your Measure object is called Value.

Apply the converter to display the column content in the DataGrid:

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
   Header="State" 
   Width="SizeToHeader"
   Binding="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource measureConv}}" 
   CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BackgroundCellStyle}"
   FontSize="20" />
```

Apply the converter to alter the style:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="BackgroundCellStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource measureConv}}" Value="Alarm">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Chartreuse"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```